# install_name_tool reporting malformed object

Tags: xcode, osx-snow-leopard, install-name-tool

Everytime I try to use install_name_tool on my machine it reports the following

```
install_name_tool: object: Abacate malformed object (unknown load command 4)
```

I read that it could be an error when building the binary. In order to check I create the simplest hello world c++ program and try to change something using install_name_tool. Didn't work. What Am I doing wrong?

Currently I have XCode 4.2 running Snow Leopard OS.

Comment: I suspect you're running an old version of `install_name_tool` left over from a previous install of Xcode. Did you install the Unix Developer Tools when you installed Xcode 4.2? What does `type -a install_name_tool` show?

Comment: Is there a way to check if I installed developer tools with XCode 4.2? `type -a install_name_tool` just give the install location `install_name_tool is /usr/bin/install_name_tool`

Comment: I would recommend that you repeat the installation of Xcode 4.2 and make sure to install the Unix Developer Tools. You can also try `pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/install_name_tool` to see what that says.

Comment: @KenThomases, you're right. `pkgutil --fine-info /usr/bin/install_name_tool` report among other things `com.apple.pkg.update.devtools.3.2.6.XcodeUpdateUNIXDevSupport`. I'll try to upgrade Unix Developer Tools.

Comment: Another thing to be aware of (and that I just fell over) is that MacPorts has its own version of `install_name_tool` provided by the package `cctools`.  Theoretically, it's just a rebuilt version of the standard cctools, but no, it seems to be broken.

Comment: In my case it was the old `install_name_tool` from MacPorts that interfered. Removing with `sudo rm -rf /opt/local/bin/install_name_tool` and relying on the one from Command Line Tools, succeeded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently install_name_tool is not updated when XCode is updated. You need to install the Command Line Tools from XCode Preferences. See also [install_name_tool on OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11598082/install-name-tool-on-os-x-lion). This resolved the same error for me.

Comment: I get this error and yet I have installed the updated commandLine Tools

Comment: I observed this too on Mavericks. I had to manually replace the one in /usr/bin with the one from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Answer (score 1):

Managed to make it work with Mac OS 10.9.3

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/26544

$$:~  otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool

> /usr/bin/install_name_tool:   /usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib (compatibility
>   version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)     /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)

$$:~  pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/install_name_tool

> volume: / path:
>   /usr/bin/install_name_tool
>   pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials pkg-version: 10.9.0.1.1.1306847324
>   install-time: 1390577801 uid: 0 gid: 0 mode: 755

No more errors on wget:

> $$:~  wget dyld: Library not loaded:
>
> @@HOMEBREW_PREFIX@@/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib   Referenced
>   from: /usr/local/bin/wget   Reason: image not found