# install_name_tool on OS X Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, install-name-tool

I'm running OS 10.7.4 and cannot find install_name_tool. I have Xcode 4.3.3 installed through the App Store. Does anyone know where I can find/get install_name_tool?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To be more precise, install the "Command Line Tools for Xcode" package from

https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action

in addition to your Xcode tools.

Which will make the tool available easily via the command line.

You can also install the command line tools via Xcode preferences in the "Downloads" pane:

[image]

+1 to Kevin for being faster than me, too.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/install_name_tool`

Comment: perfect, thanks. i guess ill put that directory in my PATH variable

Comment: Also look at `xcode-select`, it may allow you to avoid fixing the `$PATH` all the time.