# Unable to compile Actix on macOS Mojave due to "ar crs" "malformed object (unknown load command 1)"

Tags: rust, macos-mojave

I'm unable to compile a basic example using Actix. I suspect I might be missing some libraries but I have no clue of what it could be. I also upgraded to Mojave a few days ago, but I'm not sure if this is related.

It seems to complain about `ar crs` and about an internal error happening in `ranlib` when running this command.

main.rs:

```
extern crate actix_web;
use actix_web::{server, App, HttpRequest};

fn index(_req: &HttpRequest) -> &'static str {
    "Hello world!"
}

fn main() {
    server::new(|| App::new().resource("/", |r| r.f(index)))
        .bind("127.0.0.1:8088")
        .unwrap()
        .run();
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
actix-web = "0.7.8"
```

Backtrace I obtain:

```
    mbp-de-matthieu:hello-world matthieu$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo build
   Compiling backtrace-sys v0.1.24                                                                                                                                                                     
   Compiling miniz-sys v0.1.10
   Compiling brotli-sys v0.3.2
   Compiling ring v0.13.2
   Compiling tokio-current-thread v0.1.3
error: failed to run custom build command for `miniz-sys v0.1.10`
process didn't exit successfully: `/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-dc81523acb01e9e7/build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
TARGET = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
OPT_LEVEL = Some("0")
HOST = Some("x86_64-apple-darwin")
CC_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
CC_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
HOST_CC = None
CC = None
CFLAGS_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
CFLAGS_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
HOST_CFLAGS = None
CFLAGS = None
DEBUG = Some("true")
running: "cc" "-O0" "-ffunction-sections" "-fdata-sections" "-fPIC" "-g" "-fno-omit-frame-pointer" "-m64" "-Wall" "-Wextra" "-o" "/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/miniz.o" "-c" "miniz.c"
exit code: 0
AR_x86_64-apple-darwin = None
AR_x86_64_apple_darwin = None
HOST_AR = None
AR = None
running: "ar" "crs" "/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/libminiz.a" "/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/miniz.o"
cargo:warning=/usr/local/Cellar/cctools/855/bin/ranlib: object: /Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/libminiz.a(miniz.o) malformed object (unknown load command 1)
cargo:warning=ar: internal ranlib command failed
exit code: 1

--- stderr
thread 'main' panicked at '

Internal error occurred: Command "ar" "crs" "/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/libminiz.a" "/Users/matthieu/Documents/Rust/actix/hello-world/target/debug/build/miniz-sys-d59b36acd5b3db67/out/miniz.o" with args "ar" did not execute successfully (status code exit code: 1).
```

The [complete backtrace](https://pastebin.com/g59XTkAh) is too large to include on Stack Overflow.

Comment: [Update your Xcode and associated Command Line Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10390186/155423).

Comment: I already tried installing it twice along with Xcode and I still get the error (using xcode-select --install and by downloading it from the Apple Developper website).

Comment: Did you attempt compiling this before upgrading to Mojave? Does `cargo clean` before building help?

Comment: I didn't compile this before upgrading to Mojave, but I never saw an issue like this one with other crates in my projects. I also tried compiling an old project on Mojave that was compiling before and it looks fine as well. I tried using `cargo clean` before as well and the error still show up.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to work after installing cctools through MacPorts.

For some reason, installing it through brew didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

When I replaced cctools 855 with 921 from this tap then `cargo build` worked: https://github.com/dgsga/homebrew-cctools

```
brew unlink cctools
brew tap dgsga/cctools
brew install dgsga/cctools/mtoc
```

Mojave 10.14.3, Rust 1.33.0, actix-web 0.7.18